# Moving Focus out of DataGrid on Enter key press on Last row in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

How can i remove focus from a DataGrid to next control when i hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the last row of it, which is null.

I am using WPF MVVM

Comment: if you are creating user control no problem in user control that derived from data grid you still can select the data grid in xaml code you will get property explorer in left site in property explorer you can find event and after that double click on that ... it will create an event for you in code behind

Comment: i am not using codebehind since it is mvvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private void dataGrid1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
            //here we find the Row is selected
            //then we check is the row last row

            while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
            {
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }

            if (dep == null)
                return;

            if (dep is DataGridRow)
            {
                DataGridRow row= dep as DataGridRow;
                //untill here we find the selected row and here we check if it
                //the last row our focus go to next control after datagrid
               if (row.GetIndex() == dataGrid1.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                dataGrid1.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));
                dataGrid1.UnselectAll();
            }
            }
        }
```

set this event as key up of your datagrid . use this refrence too using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives . put datagrid and some other control to your window .
when you get to last row it will change focuse to next control. i will occur when you rich last row because of this **if (row.GetIndex() == dataGrid1.Items.Count - 1)**

i use datagrid with **fullrowselect as selection mode**.if you want use datagrid with cell selection mode leave comment for me please.

Comment: Its even moving to next control when i reach the first row. but what i want here is when i reach the last row and second column in null then i want to move to next control.

Comment: I dont have CodeBehind file.. I am creating a CustomDataGrid derived from DataGrid.